# temperature sensor display on top bar problems

Tags: sensors

I have been having problem getting "PSENSOR" to display in top bar... installed "Hardware Sensors Indicator" from the UbuntU repository, setup to run using "startup applications", and seems it is doing the same thing as PSENSOR!

It doesn't loadup its display on the top bar every time during startup, when it doesn't it gets corrupted so manually launching it from Unity Launcher then fails... so, it seems Ubuntu 18.04LTS has issues with the top bar display, not these two programs?

... got the same thing on my VISTA64 machine that launches on startup (not PSENSOR, but similar) and does so EVERY SINGLE TIME (not to mention standby and hibernate working so I can just hit power - then start button - and in 60 seconds up where I was last time I was on it - with UbuntU standby/hibernate just reboots - useless as is a lot of things - and takes about 6 minutes to loadup, and then half the time is unstable enough for me to have to just hold down the power button and try again - wasting sometimes a half hour just trying to get 18.04LTS to get to where I can use it... no wonder I've had to returned to microslop!)

Comment: Not 'disappearing' - just won't load up AT ALL on boot-up... most of time. AND gets corrupted so it won't load up using launcher shortcut...
(I WISH my system would just go into sleep/hibernate in the first place! ~ only shuts off, won't wake, etc.)

Comment: Sometimes when "indicator-sensors" doesn't load up automatically at bootup, I manually try Psensor next and it won't load upeither.. so I next try the command "setsid gnome-shell --replace (Use ALt F2 for command box) and Psensor will 'appear', but indicator-sensors not. Once, indicator-sensors did loadup using command - sorta a random thing?

Answer (score 0):

One of the updates 'fixed' the problem and it loads up now without the work around... loads up every time...

...guesss one of the updates 'broke' it, then months later one of the updates 'fixed' it - nothing I did!!!

life's funny :-\